# Opening notebooks

Tags: laptop-repair

I have a Compaq CQ40 which has a defective CPU fan, it seems unable to cool the notebook enough at this time, it is constantly running, and if you move the pc up/down to look under it, it makes some sort of chainsaw sound.

I have tried to take out all the screws underneath, but I still have a problem with the plastic cover on the above; I am afraid I might break it since it seem to be connected with plastic clips underneath. I have fixed notebooks before, but this one seem new, how can I open the plastic cover above without breaking it?

Any advice, tips and tricks would be so nice to have, not only for this notebook, but any future notebook also I might need to repair.

It would be nice if anyone here knows a place with video tutorials on this subject as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01531211.pdf) is the manual for your laptop. Pages 54 - 88 will be relevant for what you're hoping to do.